# How to set HADOOP_CLASSPATH for using the local filesystem with a local job runner?

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs

How to set the HADOOP_CLASSPATH for using the local filesystem with a local job runner?
How to set the input and output path from local directories?

ClassNotFoundException arises for mapper and reducer classes when I try to run with the following command.

```
hadoop WordCount input/sample.txt output
```

current value is:

: hadoop classpath

`/usr/local/hadoop/hadoop-3.2.1/etc/hadoop:/usr/local/hadoop/hadoop-3.2.1/share/hadoop/common/lib/*:/usr/local/hadoop/hadoop-3.2.1/share/hadoop/common/*:/usr/local/hadoop/hadoop-3.2.1/share/hadoop/hdfs:/usr/local/hadoop/hadoop-3.2.1/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/*:/usr/local/hadoop/hadoop-3.2.1/share/hadoop/hdfs/*:/usr/local/hadoop/hadoop-3.2.1/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/*:/usr/local/hadoop/hadoop-3.2.1/share/hadoop/mapreduce/*:/usr/local/hadoop/hadoop-3.2.1/share/hadoop/yarn:/usr/local/hadoop/hadoop-3.2.1/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/*:/usr/local/hadoop/hadoop-3.2.1/share/hadoop/yarn/*:/usr/local/hadoop/hadoop-3.2.1/etc/hadoop/usr/local/hadoop/hadoop-3.2.1/share/hadoop/common/*.jar`

versions:
Apache hadoop-3.2.1 ,
openjdk 11.0.5.

please help. It is useful for debugging. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would believe if you had FileNotFound Exception, but your classpath seems fine, so I have a hard time seeing you would get ClassNotFound Exception

Although, this path seems wrong `/usr/local/hadoop/hadoop-3.2.1/etc/hadoop/usr/local/hadoop/hadoop-3.2.1/share/hadoop/common/*.jar`.

I would suggest *moving* all files under `hadoop-3.2.1` up into `/usr/local/hadoop`, or at the very least, rename `hadoop-3.2.1` directory to just `/usr/local/hadoop/3.2.1/`

By default, Hadoop jobs use file:// paths as your `fs.defaultFS` (defined in core-site.xml)

Otherwise, if you have changed that to use `hdfs://`, then you can still use local files like so

`hadoop fs -ls file://`

To run jobs, I would suggest using [`yarn jar`](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/YarnCommands.html#jar), not `hadoop <name>`. And you need to shade your Java application into an uber-jar, or use the existing hadoop-examples JAR to run `WordCount`